# (Scirra) AJAX Request to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, construct-2

I got a problem with the [Construct 2 Editor of Scirra](https://www.scirra.com). I don't really know if this is the right place for this but, I searched for an answer a long time.

I get data of an AJAX Request, which looks like this:

```
{"data":[ [625],[500] ], [ [400],[500] ], [ [100],[120] ]}
```

Now, I don't want to get this as a string. I want to split it like

variable a = 625

variable b = 500

And so on.

Answer (score 3):

First, use the Array object to generate some data and use the `AsJSON` expression to retrieve its data.  This then shows you the format Construct 2 expects array data to be in.  Note the JSON includes additional information like the dimensions of the array, and is always saved in a 3D format, so the example you gave won't work.

Once you've got your JSON in a format Construct 2 understands, just upload it to your server and AJAX request the file.  It should load in to the Array object just fine.